# Draw a polygon with an arc along one side

Tags: c#, drawing

I am drawing a shape - with straight lines - like this:

```
PointF [] BCArray = new PointF[8];
double[,] BC = new double[,]
{
{0, 0},
{0, 77},
{45, 77},
{45, 12},
{32, 12},
{32, 27},
{15, 27},
{15, 0},
};

for (int i = 0; i < BC.Length / 2; i++)
{
double X = BC[i, 0];
double Y = BC[i, 1];
PointF buildpoint = new PointF((float)plusCD(X), (float)plusCD(Y));
BCArray.SetValue(buildpoint, i);
}

System.Drawing.Drawing2D.HatchBrush pattern = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.HatchBrush(System.Drawing.Drawing2D.HatchStyle.BackwardDiagonal, Color.Black, Color.White);
g.FillPolygon(pattern, BCArray);
```

Between the first point (0,0) and the second (0,77) I need to draw an arc. So the line goes from 0,0 to 0,10 and then in a arc with a radius of 40 until 0,50 and then on, straight to 0.77.

No idea how to do this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rather use a [GraphicsPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and fill it with [FillPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

There you can mix straight lines if *bezier curves* which may suffice for your task. I don't think you can really draw a *circle arc* with *bezier curves*, but you can approximate pretty well.

Try and let's see what you get.

To approximate a circle look at this quick tutorial: http://www.whizkidtech.redprince.net/bezier/circle/kappa/

Comment: Thanks for that. That looks like it will do the job.

Comment: I added a link to circle approximation.